# Android iText addTemplate Stamp pdf form fields overtop exisiting PDF document

Tags: android, itext, pdf-manipulation, android-droidtext

I am trying to open a standard PDF form from a legacy application in Android, overlay form fields using iText and pass to Adobe Reader on Android to fill out the form.

I have been able to create the TextFields manually but I would prefer to have a pdf file as a template to speed up the process and better control quality.

Here is the code I have so far, this follows the itext examples.

```
    AssetFileDescriptor descriptor = getAssets().openFd("standardWO_Template_v1_fo.pdf");
            File templateFile = new File(descriptor.getFileDescriptor().toString());
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(intent.getData().getPath());
            reader.selectPages("1");
            PdfReader templateReader = new PdfReader(templateFile.getAbsolutePath());
            PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(file));
            // Stamp the template onto the document
            PdfImportedPage page = stamper.getImportedPage(templateReader, 1);
            PdfContentByte cb = stamper.getOverContent(1);
            cb.addTemplate(page, 0, 0);
```

The issue I am having is on the last line. cb.addTemplate(page, 0,0);

Eclipse reports the following error. The type java.awt.geom.AffineTransform cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

From what I have been able to tell java.awt.geom.AffineTransform will not work in Android only Java.

Is there a different way to accomplish my task or get AffineTransform to work in Android?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some more searching I found this method. First I had to change from using the iText5.3.1 library in my android project to the droidText library.

Once I installed the droidText library was able to use the following code. (and a ctrl-o in eclipse)

```
    File templateFile = new File(dir.getAbsolutePath() + "/templates/standardWO.pdf");
            // Read the incoming file
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(intent.getData().getPath());
            // Read the template form information
            PdfReader templateReader = new PdfReader(templateFile.getAbsolutePath());
            // Create the stamper from the incoming file.
            PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(templateReader, new FileOutputStream(file));
            // Import the template information
            PdfImportedPage iPage = stamper.getImportedPage(reader, 1);
            // get the direct content
            PdfContentByte cb = stamper.getUnderContent(1);
            // Add the imported page to the content
            cb.addTemplate(iPage, 0, 0);
            stamper.close();
            Log.v(TAG, "Opening file in adobe reader: " + file.getAbsolutePath());
            loadDocInReader(file);
```

Comment: Hey thanks Nick, for this particular bit of info. I am trying to use pdfReader api in my java application in eclipse. This is giving a  : pdfreader cannot be resolved to a type error. Can you tell me , what to do here ?